# How to get a Java string from a char pointer in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, char, jna

I am porting the [openvr sample](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/openvr) to [jogl](https://github.com/jovr/jogl-hello-vr), after we created the [binding](https://github.com/jovr/jopenvr) with jna.

Almost at the end (before rendering the controllers and the tracking base stations), I got stuck trying to translate a char pointer in C to a String in Java.

C++ code [here](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/openvr/blob/master/samples/hellovr_opengl/hellovr_opengl_main.cpp#L308-L323):

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Purpose: Helper to get a string from a tracked device property and turn it
//          into a std::string
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
std::string GetTrackedDeviceString( vr::IVRSystem *pHmd, vr::TrackedDeviceIndex_t unDevice, vr::TrackedDeviceProperty prop, vr::TrackedPropertyError *peError = NULL )
{
    uint32_t unRequiredBufferLen = pHmd->GetStringTrackedDeviceProperty( unDevice, prop, NULL, 0, peError );
    if( unRequiredBufferLen == 0 )
        return "";

    char *pchBuffer = new char[ unRequiredBufferLen ];
    unRequiredBufferLen = pHmd->GetStringTrackedDeviceProperty( unDevice, prop, pchBuffer, unRequiredBufferLen, peError );
    std::string sResult = pchBuffer;
    delete [] pchBuffer;
    return sResult;
}
```

`GetStringTrackedDeviceProperty` [here](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/openvr/blob/master/headers/openvr.h#L1211-L1214):

```
/** Returns a string property. If the device index is not valid or the property is not a string type this function will 
* return 0. Otherwise it returns the length of the number of bytes necessary to hold this string including the trailing
* null. Strings will generally fit in buffers of k_unTrackingStringSize characters. */
virtual uint32_t GetStringTrackedDeviceProperty( vr::TrackedDeviceIndex_t unDeviceIndex, ETrackedDeviceProperty prop, VR_OUT_STRING() char *pchValue, uint32_t unBufferSize, ETrackedPropertyError *pError = 0L ) = 0;
```

Where `VR_OUT_STRING()` is defined [here](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/openvr/blob/master/headers/openvr.h#L1035-L1045) as:

```
# define VR_CLANG_ATTR(ATTR)

#define VR_OUT_STRING() VR_CLANG_ATTR( "out_string: ;" )
```

I have already done something similar where I had to call a function that expect the pointer to an array of `TrackedDevicePose_t` structures:

```
private TrackedDevicePose_t.ByReference trackedDevicePosesReference = new TrackedDevicePose_t.ByReference();
public TrackedDevicePose_t[] trackedDevicePose
            = (TrackedDevicePose_t[]) trackedDevicePosesReference.toArray(VR.k_unMaxTrackedDeviceCount);
```

I created first the reference and then from it the actual array.

But [here](https://github.com/jovr/jogl-hello-vr/blob/master/jogl-hello-vr/src/helloVr/ModelsRender.java#L75-L88) I can't have a class extending the char array..

```
private String getTrackedDeviceString(IVRSystem hmd, int device, int prop, IntBuffer propError) {

    int requiredBufferLen = hmd.GetStringTrackedDeviceProperty.apply(device, prop, Pointer.NULL, 0, propError);

    if(requiredBufferLen == 0) {
        return "";
    }


    CharArray.ByReference charArrayReference = new CharArray.ByReference();
    char[] cs = charArrayReference.toArray(requiredBufferLen);

    return null;
}
```

Where `apply` ([here](https://github.com/jovr/jopenvr/blob/master/jopenvr/src/vr/IVRSystem.java#L337-L340)) is:

```
public interface GetStringTrackedDeviceProperty_callback extends Callback {

    int apply(int unDeviceIndex, int prop, Pointer pchValue, int unBufferSize, IntBuffer pError);
};
```

CharArray class, crap attempt [here](https://github.com/jovr/jopenvr/blob/master/jopenvr/src/vr/CharArray.java)

Any ideas?

Comment: Your code is C++, not C.  These are different languages, and the differences matter.

Comment: Moreover, I don't see where Java comes into it.  If you mean to interface directly with Java then that requires JNI, and I see no JNI anywhere.  If you have a looser interaction in mind, such as via an intermediary file or pipe, then those details are important.

Comment: Yep, you are right John, thanks, I just fixed it. Java comes into with the binding, I also added that right now.

Comment: As an aside -- `pHmd->GetStringTrackedDeviceProperty`  -- If the implementation of this function `throws`, your `GetTrackedDeviceString` has a memory leak due to the `new char[ unRequiredBufferLen ];`

Comment: JNA automatically handles conversion from NUL-terminated C strings into Java `String`. It also provides `Native.toString()` to manually perform conversions.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed, but is it reliable? I mean, can I be relatively sure and modifying all the `Pointer pchValue` with a simple `String pchValue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done some porting of C and C++ code to Java, and while it's probably horribly hacky, the best I've come up with to solve cases where a pointer to an `int` primitive or a `char*`/`String` is needed for a function call, is to create a small wrapper class with a single property, pass that object into the function, change the property as needed, and retrieve the new value after the function call. So something like:

```
public class StringPointer {
    public String value = "";
}

StringPointer pchBuffer = new StringPointer();
unRequiredBufferLen = pHmd.GetStringTrackedDeviceProperty( unDevice, prop, pchBuffer, unRequiredBufferLen, peError );
String sResult = pchBuffer.value;
```

and inside `GetStringTrackedDeviceProperty()`

```
...
pchValue.value = "some string";
...
```

In this case, you can use a `String`, since that's what your code is doing with the `char*` after the function call, but if it actually really needs to be a `char[]`, you can just create `char[] pchBuffer = new char[unRequiredBufferLen];` and pass that into the function. It will be just like you were using a `char*` in C++, and any changes you make inside the array will be visible after the function ends, and you can even do `String sResult = new String(pchBuffer);`.

Comment: Interesting idea, I'll give it a try

Comment: So, about the first method, I can't to that because `GetStringTrackedDeviceProperty` is of type `interface GetStringTrackedDeviceProperty_callback` that `extends Callback` and therefore it cannot have any body. However I also tried your second tip, by changing the argument from jna `Pointer` to `char[]`, it works but I get a weird result, `桬扟獡獥慴楴湯癟癩e`, on C++ I get `lighthouse`...

Comment: The C++ part is probably using single-byte characters. If you break each `char` down into its individual bytes, does that get you the correct answer?

Comment: Switching from char to byte buffer worked, thanks dear!

Comment: You're welcome. As an aside, the first part of my answer was written under the assumption that you were porting _everything_. That's the only case where that will work. I almost deleted without posting when you mentioned you were actually interfacing with the C++ code. But I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Ps: let me just add this, using jna `Native.toString(buffer)` instead of `new String(buffer)` removes automatically any ending space